# builder.parse return null bonita soft

Tags: java, xml, bonita

Tengo una  error en la linea

```
Document doc = builder.parse(is);// doc  = null;
```

Donde al momento de utilizar el builder.parse se vuelve nulo  lo cual hacer surja el error y sea capturado por el   catch (Exception ex) diciendo que el el doc es null, estoy trabajando con bonita soft(versión 7.3) y estoy tratado de consumir un web service pero al momento de trabajar con el xml no me permite avanzar mas por el error, gracias

```js
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import java.lang.Exception;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

String ejemplo ="";
String ejemplo ="hola mundo  ";
String  aux1 ;
int n ;
boolean encontrado = false ;// bandera 

  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  
  // use the factory to create a documentbuilder
  DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  // create a new document from input source
  InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader("weatherDataAsXML"));
  try {
  Document doc = builder.parse(is);// doc  = null;
   // get the first element
  Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
   // get all child nodes
  NodeList nodes = element.getChildNodes();
   // print the text content of each child
   for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
   //    
    ejemplo = ejemplo +""+ nodes.item(i).getTextContent();
     
  }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
  
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement =ex.getStackTraceElement(0);
        n = stackTraceElement.length;

        for (int i = 0 ;i<n;i++ )
  {
  ejemplo = ejemplo+ " "+stackTraceElement[i].getLineNumber()+">>"+stackTraceElement[i].getMethodName();
  }   
  } catch (SAXException e) { 
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  

return ejemplo;
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetMortgagePayment xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
      <Years>10</Years>
      <Interest>0.7</Interest>
      <LoanAmount>1000000</LoanAmount>
      <AnnualTax>0.5</AnnualTax>
      <AnnualInsurance>0.9</AnnualInsurance>
    </GetMortgagePayment>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: Y el stackTrace, parece que el InputStream es el null no tanto la construcción .

Comment: por que cuando capturo el valor de is  antes de entrar al  try catch es de  is = org.xml.sax.InputSource@4f464311 pero al ejecutar la siguiente linea  "Document doc = builder.parse(is);// doc  = null;"y entonces doc se vuelve null y sale el error no tengo idea que hacer para solucionar el error, gracias

Comment: Agrega el StackTrace por favor

Comment: ya he agregado  el stackTrace al código y me  indica  -1(stackTraceElement[i].getLineNumber())">>parse(stackTraceElement[i].getMethodName())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la solución la pude realizar utilizando la librería externa  XStream

```js
XStream xstream = new XStream(); 
String xml = xstream.toXML(aux); 
if ("Data Not Found".equalsIgnoreCase(weatherDataAsXML))
return null; 
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(); 
inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(aux)); 
try {
Document weatherDataDocument = documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);
```

ya que el problema que esta teniendo era que al momento de utilizar el parse no me esta leyendo el paraméntro como si fuera un xml por ese motivo lo envía null